# Unable to return a subtype from a WCF RIA Silverlight service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ria

I have an WCF RIA Silverlight project in which I've added a few general methods (i.e. not entity queries).  These work fine and I am able to return my own domain objects.  My problem is that if I try to return a subtype (e.g. FooData below instead of Data) my service call blows up with a non-helpful NotFound error in the async execution.

```
public Data GetData() { }
public class Data { }
public class FooData : Data { }
```

I'm using VS 2010 SP1 so it hasn't been necessary for me to mark them up in any way so far.  But I was lead to believe I might have to add a KnownType attribute.  I tried placing a [KnownType(typeof(FooData)] on the Data class but I get an error telling me that I cannot place that attribute on a complex type.

Should WCF be able to return polymorphic types in this way?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these.

http://systemmetaphor.blogspot.com/2010/01/wcf-ria-services-using-inheritance.html
http://martinkruszynski.blogspot.com/2010/02/wcf-ria-services-part-iii-inheritance.html

Comment: I'm afraid that these do not help.  The first one (which confuses the terms superclass and subclass) appears to show the usage of the KnownType attribute.  However when I try to use KnownType on the Data class as described in my post above I get an error telling me that you cannot place it on a complex type.  If anyone has a working example of a WCF service that returns polymorphic types I'd love to see it.  Thanks - Pat.

Comment: I was able to get the first example to work.  I didn't use complextype though, just a couple pocos.  I was also able to place the KnownType att. on a complextype.  How are you doing that?  Are you creating a partial of the complextype?

Comment: Thanks - After many hours of fighting with it I tried switching the code to a plain WCF service for silervlight (as opposed to the RIA linq to entity service) and was able to get an example working.  I think that there is something wrong with WCF RIA services for silverlight...

Comment: Odd, I'm using WCF RIA, even if you're using Linq you can inherit from just DomainService.

Comment: When I say "plain WCF service" I should clarify that what I did was use the template for "Silverlight enabled WCF service".  I think that solved a number of problems that I was having including the inheritance issue as well as not being able to return compound types like List<List<>> and also not being able to return type object for heterogeneous collections....  All started working when I switched to the silverlight enabled WCF service from the linq to entities domain service template... (And I did not need the entity query features on the client side in this case so it didn't matter).  Thks.